# Splitting a paragraph into an array and animating each contents of the array on button click

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="button">Click!</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
     let para = document.createElement("p");
     para.textContent = "Text message one. Text message two. Text message three.";
     let strText = para.textContent;
     let splitText = strText.split(".");
     
     for (let i=0; i<splitText.length;i++) {
     splitText.textContent += "<span>" + splitText[i] + "</span>";
     }
     container.appendChild(splitText[i]);
});
```

I AM STUCK! How can I write my code such that onclicking the button, the array components of the paragraph is shown(animated) on the div one after another ??
I know about the css animation and transition but I just don't know how to apply it here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const button = document.querySelector("#button");

let idx = 0;
let sentnce = "Text message one. Text message two. Text message three.";
let texts = sentnce.split(".").slice(0, -1);

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (idx < texts.length) {
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = texts[idx];
        container.appendChild(p);
        ++idx;
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <button id="button">Click!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I think a `reduce` is better than a `join`, followed by the enclosure of `spans` inside `<span>` tags.

Comment: @NiceBooks, yes, you are right. it is more performant. You can post an answer for the reduce version. I use `join` is for clarity.

Comment: I think he wants the text to be split at `.` and then make each sentence appear in a `smooth` fashion with every click.

Comment: @AliMustafa, haha, you are right. See my updates.

Comment: Yes something like that but I want the "text messages" to appear one after another on a single click in such away that when "Text message two" appears "Text message one" fades away and it is replaced by text two, and so on up-to the last text. I had suggested the use of css animation, I just don't know how to apply it sequentially